# Storing of S3 Keys vs URLs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have some functionality that uploads Documents to an S3 Bucket.

The key names are programmatically generated via some proprietary logic for the layout/naming convention needed.

The results of my S3 upload command is the actual url itself. So, it's in the format of

`REGION/BUCKET/KEY`

I was planning on storing that full url into my DB so that users can access their uploads.

Given that REGION and BUCKET probably wouldn't change, does it make sense to just store the KEY - and then dynamically generate the full url when the client needs it?

Just want to know what the desired pattern here is and what others do. Thanks!

Comment: "probably" is a keyword there. Be extremely cautious when making any decision that's difficult to change later.

Comment: I generally store the entire URL of the document. That makes it much easier to recompose, as you will need the entire URL to sign it in order for it to be downloaded. In addition, the space you save vs the additional complexity you gain is negligible.

Answer (score 3):

Storing the full URL is a bad idea. As you said in the question, the region and bucket are already known, so storing the full URL is a waste of disk space. Also, if in the future say, you want to migrate your assets to a different bucket may be in a different region, having full URLs stored in the DB just make things harder.